# T-SQL select rows by oldest date and unique category

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using Microsoft SQL.  I have a table that contains information stored by two different categories and a date.  For example:

```
ID   Cat1   Cat2   Date/Time   Data  
1    1      A      11:00       456
2    1      B      11:01       789
3    1      A      11:01       123
4    2      A      11:05       987
5    2      B      11:06       654
6    1      A      11:06       321
```

I want to extract one line for each unique combination of Cat1 and Cat2 and I need the line with the oldest date.  In the above I want ID = 1, 2, 4, and 5.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried something and got stacked or just want complete solution from nothing?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hmm, well the link that you so helpfully called FAQ doesn't seem to say anything about listing all of the "that doesn't work" answers.  It also suggests that if I ask a vague question I will get an answer similar... makes sense to me.  Problem is I got a fantastic answer that I wouldn't have though of in a million years.  As for what didn't work, well I'd hate to explain all of the different things I tried that don't work like selecing distinct because it doesn't return anything in a specific order nor does it actually return the data I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) on MSDN.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date_time, id) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

(run the code on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/668a0/1))

Comment: Cool.  That does the trick.  I also didn't know about SQL Fiddle, that's neat.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quassnoi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221569/263232) is fine, but I'm a bit uncomfortable with how it handles dups.  It seems to return based on insertion order, but I'm not sure if even that can be guaranteed?  (see these two fiddles for an example where the result changes based on insertion order: [dup at the end](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87a09/1), [dup at the beginning](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d77ca/1))

Plus, I kinda like staying with old-school SQL when I can, so I would do it this way (see [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ce68/1) for how it handles dups):

```
select *
from my_table t1
  left join my_table t2
    on t1.cat1 = t2.cat1
    and t1.cat2 = t2.cat2
    and t1.datetime > t2.datetime
where t2.datetime is null
```

Comment: see my post update, it will now return the first `id` in case of a tie. Your query will return all duplicates in case of a tie. Window functions can do this as well, just replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`.